# When are SharedPreferences deleted?

Tags: android

SharedPreferences  class allows to save application data in simple type (boolean, String, etc.) formats.

Normally they are not removed and they are supposed to persist, but are they removed in case such as when application is updated/removed or application cache is cleared?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

when you do `clear data` from the device applications `manager` or when you uninstall your application, the SharedPreference's file is deleted.

SharePreferences are stored inside

```
/data/data/packagename/shared_prefs/prefsname.xml
```

unless you have the `android:allowBackup="true"` in your manifest. In that case they might be restored.

Comment: but this file location is not found I tried 100 times. Could you tell me how to search this folder, please?

Comment: wait, `packagename` is the actual package of your application, it is usually something like `com.something.appname`. To access /data/data you need a rooted device, if you are using adb to look for it @Mohini

Comment: I am using eclipse with usb debug mode, please tell me how to search this folder?

Comment: you need a rooted device for that. Try with the emulator @Mohini

Comment: I think you could use a tool call file explorer. It should be part of the ADT @Mohini

Answer (score 4):

1. `Sharedpreferences` will clear when you clear application data from Application manager by force.
2. If you want to clear your application Sharepreference data, then you can use:

   ```
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().commit();
   ```

Comment: that wae a cause in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Setting`->`Application setting`->`Application`->`Clear data` and force data will clear all the data of application (sqlitedatabase and shared preferences) are removed.