# How long does SharedPreferences save data?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making an Android app, and I will do some process at the first launch of the app.After the first launch I will not these process again. So, for doing this, I want to use SharedPrefences.
How long does it save data? When and how does its saved datas remove?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SharedPreference security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244318/android-sharedpreference-security)

Comment: @ADM it's not about SharedPrefernces security

Comment: Read the answers in link first if you are not satisfied, then comment here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566428/when-are-sharedpreferences-deleted

Comment: SP will be deleted on clear data and app uninstallation .

Answer (score 6):

Data in SharedPrefences is saved until the user uninstalls the app, or clears the app cache

Answer (score 3):

Data in SharedPrefences is saved as file in your app internal storage, its be removed in case:

- unInstall app
- clear you app data
- call `yourSharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()`

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

When you clear the cash memory form settings all the information will be deleted and start fully new. so it not exactly that you need to uninstall your app.

So **sharedpreferences** is basically store data in primitive way which mean it doesn't contain data directly instead it's reference.